# R order list of tables by column and selecting top 100 rows

Tags: r, list, apply

I am working with a large list `results.list` that contains 22 tables (23544 obs of 6 variables).

I want to sort each table by a specific column (FDR) False Discovery rate and select the first 100 rows. I can do this manually using my simple **R** commands.

```
attach(results.list$adult.OLFvsVTA)
sort(FDR)
detach(results.list$adult.OLFvsVTA)
adult.OLFvsVTA100<-adult.OLFvsVTA[1:100,]
```

I want to combine the top 100 rows from all 22 tables. I do not want the FDR values in the combined vector but rather I want to combine the top 100 rows by one column named (genes). I would like to automate this process using an apply function. Despite a series of attempts I can not get it to work. I created another vector called `r.names` that contains the names of all 22 tables in my list that I was planning to feed into my apply function. I read several apply help pages but I can't get it to work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean "22 tables"? Do you have 22 variables or do you have a variable in `results.list` that indicates the "table" of each observation?

Comment: What do you expect your final result to look like?  A 2200 row by `ncol(results.list$adult.OLFvsVTA)` column data frame, or a 100 row by 22 * `ncol(results.list$adult.OLFvsVTA)` data frame?  Related, how do you combine any two of your tables using the `genes` column?

Comment: josilber: instead of tables I meant to say data.frame with the dimensions (23544 obs (number of rows) of 6 variables (number of columns, one of those columns is called FDR one is called genes).

Comment: BrodiG: I am hoping to get an output file containing 2200 gene names from the column genes from each file. It could be a data frame 1 column with 2200 rows.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296646/how-to-sort-a-dataframe-by-columns-in-r

Comment: is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(results.list, function(dd) { dd[with(dd, order(FDR)),][(1:100), ]}))
```

so assuming results.list is a list of data frames we want to apply (lapply is for lists) the function that sorts them by FDR and grabs the first 100 rows (function(dd) {....} <- stolen from other stackoverflow post for sorting by column)  to each data frame.  The result of this will be a list of data frames.  We can call do.call which is a fancy function that takes a **function** and a list where the list will be decomposed from a list to the arguments for our **function**.  In this case our function is rbind will will take the **X** number of 100 row tables and create one big table.  Let me know if you want further explanation.

Comment: Hi Andrew, I tried something similar before and it didn't work. When I try your solution I get the following error message. Error in `[.data.frame`(dd, with(dd, order(FDR)), 1:100) : 
  undefined columns selected

Comment: can you post colnames(results.list[[1]] or any other table in your list).  That will help me out.  You may want "FDR"

Comment: ahh nvm.  Give me a second I'll update with correct form

Comment: I think it has something to do with the list structure. the results list contains 22 elements and each element contains a data frame with 6 columns and many rows.     str(results.list)
List of 22
$ adult.HYPvsVTA   :'data.frame': 23544 obs. of  6 variables:
  ..$ genes : Factor w/ 23544 levels "0610005C13Rik",..: 2889 15734 7816 17776 13955 8896 2354 7653 6502 5857 ...
  ..$ logFC : num [1:23544] 9.66 9.21 8.05 -6.23 11.12 ...
  ..$ logCPM: num [1:23544] ..
  ..$ LR    : num [1:23544]  ...
  ..$ PValue: num [1:23544]  .
  ..$ FDR   : num [1:23544] ...

Comment: colnames(results.list[[1]])
[1] "genes"  "logFC"  "logCPM" "LR"     "PValue" "FDR"

Comment: names(results.list)
 [1] "SN.adultvse15.5"   "SN.p2vse15.5"      "SNadultvsp2"       "VTA.adultvse15.5"  "VTA.p2vse15.5"    
 [6] "VTA.adultvsp2"     "p2.SNvsVTA"        "e15.5.SNvsVTA"     "e15.5.SNnegvsSN"   "adult.SNnegvsSN"  
[11] "e15.5.SNnegvsVTA"  "adult.SNnegvsVTA"  "adult.OLFvsSNe15"  "adult.HYPvsSNe15"  "adult.OLFvsVTAe15"
[16] "adult.HYPvsVTAe15" "adult.HYPvsOLF"    "adult.HYPvsSN"     "adult.HYPvsVTA"    "adult.OLFvsSN"    
[21] "adult.OLFvsVTA"    "adult.SNvsVTA"

Comment: Thanks a lot it works flawless and I actually understand your explanation. I will be able to transfer it to my next question!! Have a great day